Obtaining analytic solution for coupled nonlinear ode
I've been trying non stop to solve a system of two coupled nonlinear ordinary differential equations.
I've tried several change of variables as well as transformations and none have borne any fruit.
Any advice on alternative ways to approach it would be greatly appreciated.
The system is as follows:
$$
Y^{\prime} = a_{1}-a_{2}Z+a_{3}Y^{2}\\
Z^{\prime}=a_{4}Y
$$
here $a_{1,2,3,4}$ all real coefficients
Once again any advice is appreciated.
Thank you

What transformations have been done or why do they not work?

Apart from the transformation mentioned by JJacquelin below, some of the more noteworthy ones I've tried are u=1/Y ; u =Y^2; u = YZ; Stokes variables, polar coordinates. These all result in considerably more complex Differential equations with much worse nonlinearities

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{dy}{dx} = a_{1}-a_2 z+a_3 y^2\\
\frac{dz}{dx}=a_4 y
\end{cases} \quad\implies\quad \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-a_2 a_4 y+2a_3 y\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=u(y)\quad\implies\quad \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{du}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=u\frac{du}{dy}$$
$$u\frac{du}{dy}=-a_2 a_4 y+2a_3 y\,u$$
$$u\frac{du}{-a_2 a_4 +2a_3u}=ydy$$
Integration :
$$\frac12 y^2=\frac{u}{4a_3}+\frac{a_2a_4}{4(a_3)^2}\ln|a_2a_4-2a_3u |+\text{constant}$$
Solving for $u(y)$ involves a special function namely the LambertW function.
After having explicitely the function $u(y)$ :
$$x(y)=\int \frac{dy}{u(y)}$$
The inverse function is the wanted $y(x)$ .
Then integrating wrt $x$ leads to the wanted $z(x)$ .
This the the theoretical very arduous way. In practice don't waste time to try this theoretical way. Better use numerical calculus starting directly from the initial system of equations.

Thank you very much! I'll look into the LambertW function to expand my toolbox.
